# mysql COUNT and Sum with join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum

I have tried many queries with no right result

my goal is to get user commission based on userid attend to branchid and how many users was attended on same day on same branch;

want have result like so

| Date | totalAtt | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-1 | 1 | 60 <-(50+20)-(5+5) |
| 2022-05-2 | 2 | 50 <-(50+20)-(5+15) |
| 2022-05-3 | 3 | 80 <-(80+30)-(25+5) |
| 2022-05-4 | 1 | 200 <-(100+200)-(50+50) **was on branchid =5** |

from the 2 tables below
**money**

| ID | Date | branchId | ca | ce | car | cer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-1 | 7 | 50 | 20 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-05-1 | 5 | 100 | 20 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-05-2 | 7 | 50 | 20 | 5 | 15 |
| 4 | 2022-05-2 | 5 | 70 | 20 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 | 2022-05-3 | 7 | 80 | 30 | 25 | 5 |
| 6 | 2022-05-3 | 5 | 90 | 20 | 35 | 5 |
| 7 | 2022-05-4 | 7 | 80 | 30 | 25 | 5 |
| 8 | 2022-05-4 | 5 | 100 | 200 | 50 | 50 |

**att**

| ID | date | userid | branchId | att |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-1 | 20 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-2 | 20 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-05-2 | 21 | 7 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-05-3 | 20 | 7 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-05-3 | 21 | 7 | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-05-3 | 22 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-05-4 | 20 | 5 | 1 |

thanks in Advanced

Comment: "get user commission based on userid attend to branchid and how many users was attended on same day on same branch" is not clear. "based on" means nothing in particular. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. A question re how you are 1st stuck will be a duplicate. [Re research.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] If asking give a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the existing which fetch correct values but not based on userid
other word WITHOUT    
   `WHERE userid=20`
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f68dc28cbb13d337772e3a0d5952ee6)
when use
   `WHERE a.userid =20`
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8dd4fdddabb410475b54c08091c1f16e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to count att by date but amount for a specified user. So conditionally aggregate

```
SELECT 
  a.date, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.USERID) AS totalatt ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN USERID = 20 THEN (m.ca+m.ce)-(m.car+m.cer) END) AS amount
FROM att a
LEFT JOIN money m   ON a.date = m.date   AND a.branchid = m.branchid
GROUP BY a.date HAVING AMOUNT > 0
ORDER BY a.date;
```

Comment: i think "conditionally aggregate " was the secret word  , Many thanks